What is "void (0)"?
I know that (void)0 is a no-op in C/C++.
However, when I was looking through the code in <cassert>, I saw void (0).
I guess it's something like int (0) or int{0}.
I also tried void{} and it works.
It seems that this is a zero-initialization for void.
But void is an incomplete type, how come the compiler doesn't complain?  (g++-14 -std=c++23 -Wall)

void(0) is a function-style cast expression, and void expressions are valid in C++. Similar for void{}. C++ has special rules for cast expressions to void.

@WeijunZhou: Thanks.  This can be posted as an answer.

Along similar lines, you can do void foo() { return void(); }. This usage here would be a silly novelty, but it does have a real purpose with templates and the T=void, T foo() { return T(); }

@shynur Will do when I'm not on mobile.

It's a good question IMO, tho something arrogant downvoted it.

Void is incomplete type in C. In C++ it's not quite so, because otherwise a number of statements would be IFNDR, but they are explicitly described, e.g. return void()

Both void(0) and void{} are function-style explicit type conversion expressions in the standard, and the semantics are defined as follows,

If the initializer is a parenthesized single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent to the corresponding cast expression. Otherwise, if the type is cv void and the initializer is () or {} (after pack expansion, if any), the expression is a prvalue of type void that performs no initialization.

For void(0), the first sentence applies, and the expression is semantically equivalent to (void)0, which you already know about. To further expand, this is equivalent to static_cast<void>(0) where the standard makes a special case for cv void in expr.static.cast. For void{}, the second sentence comes into play, and the standard explicitly specifies that no initialization is performed. In either case, there is no "initialization of incomplete type" involved, and that explains why the compiler doesn't complain.

The special rule for void{} was however added relatively late with https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2351.html as a DR mid 2017, so older compilers may not accept it.

When you write T(E) in C++ where T is a type and E a single expression, then that is called a functional-style cast expression and exactly equivalent to the old-style cast expression (T)E in terms of semantics.
So void(0) is exactly equivalent to (void)0.
(There are some parsing differences in terms of operator precedence and what the grammar permits T to contain exactly.)
